# Maximal almos disjoint family isn't $C^{*}$-embedded.

Tags: general-topology

I'm workin with an exercise of topology but I don't know how to solve it. First, some context:

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a maximal almost disjoint family such that $|\mathcal{M}|=2^{\aleph_0}$ and consider $\psi=\omega\cup\mathcal{M}$ be the Mrowka space asociated to $\mathcal{M}$ with the open basis
$$B=\{\{n\}\mid n\in\omega \}\cup\{\{M\}\cup S\mid M\in\mathcal{M} \ \text{and $S$ is a cofinite subset of $M$ } \}$$
I need to prove that $\mathcal{M}$ is not $C^{*}$-embedded in $\psi$ (in general, $S\subseteq X$ is $C^{*}$-embedded in $X$ if every bounded continuous function $f:S\to\mathbb{R}$ has a continuous bounded extension $g:X\to\mathbb{R}$). But, how can I prove that? Searching in some topology books, I have encountered my exercise with a hint in Porter's book so called Extensions and Absolutes of Hausdorff Spaces:

[image: Hint]

In another question I asked, I proved the fact that $\mathcal{M}$ is a zero set, but, again, I can't prove the hint! Anyone can help me?

After a lot of tries, my professor gave me a list of steps to prove the hint, but I suspect that the steps are wrong. The steps are the next:

1.- Take $\mathcal{N}\subseteq\mathcal{M}$ such that $|\mathcal{N}|=\aleph_0$. Then $\mathcal{N} = \{N_0,...,N_n,...\}$ where $N_i \not= N_j$ if $i \not= j$.

2.- By the definition of almost disjoint family, we can take $x_0 \in N_0$, $x_1 \in N_1 \setminus N_0$,..., $x_n \in N_n \setminus \bigcup_{i < n}N_i$, ...

3.- Let $F = \{x_0,...,x_n,...\}$. Prove that $|F|=\aleph_0$ and that there exist $T \in \mathcal{M}$ such that $T = F \cup G$ where $G$ is a finite subset of $\omega$. Prove that $T \in \text{cl}_\psi (F)$ and $T \not= N_i$ for all $i < \omega$.

The step 3 is false. If $F\in\mathcal{M}$ then we are done, but, if not? Then there exist $M\in\mathcal{M}$ such taht $M\cap F$ is infinite. But, then, is impossible that $F\cup  G$ be an element of $\mathcal{M}$, with $G$ a finite subset of $\omega$, since $M\cap F\subseteq M\cap (F\cup G)$. I really appreciate any help you can provide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The almost disjoint family $\mathscr{M}$ is maximal, and $F$ is an infinite subset of $\omega$, so there must be an $M\in\mathscr{M}$ such that $F$ and $M$ are not almost disjoint, i.e., such that $M\cap F$ is infinite. Let $U$ be a basic open nbhd of $M$, say $U=\{M\}\cup(M\setminus A)$, where $A$ is a finite subset of $M$; then $U\cap F=(M\setminus A)\cap F=(M\cap F)\setminus A$ is infinite and therefore non-empty. That is, every basic open nbhd of $M$ meets $F$, so $M\in\operatorname{cl}F$.

And $F$ is almost disjoint from each $N_i\in\mathscr{N}$, so $M\notin\mathscr{N}$, i.e., $M\ne N_i$ for $i\in\omega$.